# Accessing module in ruby iterators

Tags: ruby, module, iterator

Can't seem to find this anywhere:

```
Module::ModelClassOne.all.each do
  Module::ModelClassTwo.all.each do
    # get an error of undefined constant ModelClassTwo
  end
end
```

What gives?  I have tried a few different alternatives:

```
Module::ModelClassOne.all.each do
  ::Module::ModelClassTwo.all.each do
    # get an error of undefined constant ModelClassTwo
  end
end
```

and

```
Module::ModelClassOne.all.each do
  ModelClassTwo.all.each do
    # get an error of undefined constant ModelClassTwo
  end
end
```

and

```
Module::ModelClassOne.each do
  ::ModelClassTwo.each do
    # get an error of undefined constant ModelClassTwo
  end
end
```

Nothing works and it's making me crrrrrrazzzzzy.

Comment: You must have a typo somewhere in you code. Accessing class identifiers has nothing to do with the depth of your iteration loop. `ModelClassTwo` should be available everywhere regardless of loop depth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `each` method doesn't redefine the execution context so this is probably a case of `ModelClassTwo` not being defined as you expect.

Make sure `ModelClassTwo` is actually loaded. You may have forgotten to `require` that file.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, very embarrassing.  It totally was a typo and had a lot to do with how how rake tasks spit out errors.  I was trying to assign model.attributes = { option: option.id } instead of model.attributes = { option_id: option.id } and it was giving me an error of "unitialized constant Option" coming form the attributes hash.  Been working too long here.  What a terrible second question to ask on here.  Sorry guys and gals!